# Shopify GET webhooks requests

Tags: api, httprequest, shopify

I'm trying to fetch all the webhooks we use in our Private APP like so:

```
request.get({
    url: `https://${shop}.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json`,
    oauth: {
        oauth_token: accessToken
    }
}, (error, response, body) => {
    const webhook = JSON.parse(body)
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        resolve.json({ webhook, status: 201 })
    } else {
        resolve.json({ error: 'Did not get list of webhooks', status: 500, response: response, err: error })
    }
    reject('Could not get customer activation URL')
})
```

But I get an error 500 when I try to return the data.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a correctly structured call. There is no oauth parameter to any API endpoint in Shopify API calls. Instead, you use the token issued to you by using an oAuth exchange with the API in the header. The API will return to you the webhooks made in the shop with the API key you used to generate the token.

As per sample code from Shopify...

```
const shopRequestUrl = 'https://' + shop + '/admin/webhooks.json';
const shopRequestHeaders = {
  'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken,
};

request.get(shopRequestUrl, { headers: shopRequestHeaders })
  .then((shopResponse) => {
  res.end(shopResponse);
})
.catch((error) => {
  res.status(error.statusCode).send(error.error.error_description);
});
```